# Swift - Missing argument label 'where:' in call but fixing causes a "cannot convert value of type Bool to expected" error

Tags: json, swift, parsing, conditional-statements

I am trying to access parsed JSON data in an if statement and it outputs the following error:

> Missing argument label 'where:' in call

When I resolve the error by clicking `fix` it gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type '(Status) throws -> Bool'

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

// JSON parsing
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let greeting: String
    let instructions: [Instruction]
}
struct Instruction: Decodable {
    let statuses: [Status]
    let message, messageURL: String
    let status: Bool
    let load, time: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statuses, message
        case messageURL = "message_url"
        case status, load, time
    }
}
struct Status: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let code: Int
    let status: Bool
    let time: Int
}

//main class
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Hides the status bar
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    //Storyboard controllers
    @IBOutlet weak var downImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var upImage: UIImageView!

    //The meat of the program
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = "https://issteamdown.com/status.json"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Instruction.self, from: data)
                json.statuses.forEach { status in
                    if !json.statuses.contains(where: false) {
                        print("all true")

                        // show the image view
                        self.upImage.isHidden = false
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

If someone can please assist me with this error, I would be very grateful. I have tried searching but the solutions offered by similar questions don't seem to be very helpful or I am not implementing them correctly.

If someone could help me understand what is going on here, that would be fantastic of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just read the error message. "Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type '(Status)'..." The compiler is saying, quite clearly: How can a Status be `false`? And the compiler is quite right. It is the Status's `status` that can be `false`, not the Status itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand that last part. Are you saying to un-capitalize it?

Comment: In a way... Carpsen's answer gives you the right answer about what to _say_. I'm trying to show you how to _think_.

Answer (score 2):

[`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) expects a closure that returns a bool:

```
if !json.statuses.contains(where: {$0.status == false}) {
    print("all true")
    self.upImage.isHidden = false
}
```

`json.statuses` is an array of type `[Status]`, and you want to check if no element of that array has a `status == false` .

---

As noted by **@MartinR** in the comments, you can write the above condition more elegantly like so:

```
if json.statuses.allSatisfy ({ $0.status }) {
    print("all true")
    self.upImage.isHidden = false
}
```

To learn more about closures, have a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Comment: As of Swift 4.2 you can use `statuses.allSatisfy { $0.status }`

Comment: Thank you! This worked! If you don't mind, could you please explain to me what exactly the curly brackets and the `$0.` does exactly, as opposed to what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @bluewizard3: You might want to re-read the chapter about closures in the Swift Language Reference.

Comment: @MartinR Another day, a new thing we all learn from you. I'll include it in the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @OOPer I've just realized that and came to find your comment.

Comment: Seems my comment was extraneous. As far as I tested, with removing `!`, Xcode claims we need `(` `)`, does your Xcode say nothing with your new code?

Comment: @OOPer yep parentheses needed, and your comment is anything but extraneous. Thank you for helping the community!